# Photoshop: Pasting PNG from the web turns transparency black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, paint.net, copy-and-paste

I have searched for a solution to this problem and I have found many answers, all of which tell me that this is not an issue with Photoshop, but an issue with Windows. They will tell me: "The Windows clipboard does not preserve transparency of a PNG image".

The only problem is, when I paste such an image into the free, open-sourced image editing program Paint.Net, there are no issues at all and the transparency is retained just fine. This would imply to me that the Windows clipboard is preserving the transparency, and Photoshop is somehow turning it black.

Does anyone know if there are some settings in PS keeping me from pasting transparent PNG images?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I have also read that some say that Windows clipboard is the problem, but it appears to be bug in the Windows version Photohsop that Adobe has never fixed, because it works just fine in other software such as GIMP and Inkscape.  I'm voting to close this question because it's an issue Adobe would need to fix, and tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: A workaround is to save the image from your browser, and then place the PNG in Photoshop.

Comment: kinda weird to have such a glaring issue on the best software money can buy.

Comment: All software can have bugs. Doesn't matter how much it costs. I doubt there is such a thing as totally perfect software with no bugs.

Comment: Best software, five me a break. Well, yes the windows clipboard does not include alpha. Sortof, this is true. Windows clipboard works by client application registering a number of things they can pass, and then a lowest denominator widows api item. The lowest denominator item can not pass alpha. But offcourse the aplication you cut from can include anything it wants and hope the other application understands this. So if you include the pbg thats fine but only some applications will understand this, and only some can pass it. Theres no general rule that says this is true.

Comment: In general Adobes support for PNG is a bit lackluster to begin with. It does not support all png formats. Its perfectly normal for adobe not to open certain PNGs and making pngs that technically break PNG specification. But big players behave like that, think of how word, excel, matlab, Microsoft as company, Apple as company etc behave

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old solution I found that might work:
Right click on the image and select "Copy image link".
Then in Photoshop, while a document is open, go to File-Place Embedded.
When the dialog box opens place the link in the file name and click on Place.
The image should open as a smart object.
Here's the workspace on a png I just copied:

[image]